# Set max number of threads in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am using Flask as service for requests that execute heavy processing tasks. I want to use multi threading. I made a test and opened 100 threads. I'm afraid that the service will crash at some n threads. The max execution concurrency will be 10 a week. Where do I define the max running threads?

Comment: You should look at running your heaving processing tasks in separate worker processes using something like [Celery](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). It's easy to integrate with Flask (use Flask to start new tasks with a POST request)

Comment: There is no way to configure the max open threads?

Comment: Flask runs in one thread. You'd have to use something like [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) to run multiple threads. What did you use to open 100 threads?

Comment: If I run the server like that "app.run(threads=true) " it open threades.

Comment: Flask only includes a builtin server for development. Don't use it to run in production: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/